# How can I securely read a password from the console in Java while redirecting stdout?

Tags: java, console-application

I'm using this fairly straightforward code to read a password from the console:

```
String s = new String(System.console().readPassword("Enter password:"));
```

When I run this from the command like like this:

```
$ java Foo
Enter password:
```

All is well. But if I redirect standard output, I get:

```
$ java Foo > /dev/null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Foo.main(Foo.java:122)
```

(line 122 is the one shown above)

It's odd that redirecting `stdout` should kill the console, but I can sort of understand why this may be happening.

Rather than getting an NPE, I'd like to work-around this in some way, but I'm not sure there are any other facilities in Java that allow reading a sensitive value from the keyboard without echoing the characters.

Are there other strategies that are reliable? I suspect that I might be able to use ANSI escapes to put the terminal into a particular mode, but I don't know how reliable those can be from Java.

Comment: Please explain how you "redirect the output". Your two examples are doing the exact same thing?!

Comment: I can't be sure that's the problem, since your post is confusing, but consider that if you're redirecting input/output, there's no actual console, so `System.console()` returns `null`, hence your NPE

Comment: Apologies for the copy/paste-with edits errors. I have added the shell output redirection that was missing in the second example.

Comment: I think you added it to the wrong example.

Comment: *sigh* SO post-fail.

Comment: Any redirection will prevent you from using the console.  You could use a command line parameter to _mute_ the output or redirect it to a file.

Comment: I'm not married to `System.console()`... I just want to be able to read from the *command-line console*. The term is, unfortunately, overloaded. This is not a question about whether or not I can use `System.console`, it's about how I can read a password securely, through any means.

Comment: Define "securely". If your problem is not showing it on the console, load it from a file instead and let the operating system handle that file's security (as does ssh, for example).

Comment: The question asks about reading it from the console, not from a file. Note that ssh typically is file + password (read from the console, coincidentally).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need, but if possible you can load the password from the console as you did in the beginning of the application, and then programmatically redirect the system output to nowhere for the rest of the execution

```java
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
                // don't write to nowhere
                public void write(int b) { }
            }));
```

and in JDK11 you can do

```java
System.setOut(new PrintStream(OutputStream.nullOutputStream()));
```